# Sampling tiles in regular grid with Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to extract tiles of size 256x256 from an `ee.Image` over regions where I have labeled data. I understand how to take a random sample within polygons from an object returned from ee.Image.neighborhoodToArray() by using sample(), but I need a uniform sample over a grid defined by the extent of the labels. The image below shows an example of a label raster overlaid with tiles that I need to extract.
[image: Example of tiles that I need to extract.]
I understand I could do it by generating points in a uniform grid over my label shapefile and sampling at those points, but this seems cumbersome. Is there functionality in Earth Engine to do this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly the intended use, but you could use `sampleRegions` to handle generating a grid of points that overlap an image and a region of interest. You would have to calculate the meter `scale` that gets you the right point spacing in your projection.

```
Map.addLayer(image.select(0).sampleRegions({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection([geometry]),
  scale: 20000,
  geometries: true,
}));
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8bbde09b6b92f87bdab7efaeb18c6a1f